# In angular dart is there a way to break early from a "foreach" loop

Tags: angular-dart

I saw that this is already answered for javascript but is there a way to break out of an forEach loop in angular dart.

```
  bool hasValue() {
    bool result = false;
    periods.forEach((item) {
      if (item.hasValue()) {
        result = true;
        //PENDING...Break out of loop early
      }
    });

    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot break forEach loop.

You can try this code instead:

```
 for(var item in items) {
  final value = item['unit_value'];
  if (value.isNotEmpty) {
    break;
  }
}
```